# Get Response from Dialog Share URL in Javascript (without FB.ui)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following URL for Facebook Sharing in Javascript:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=MY_APP&display=popup&href=MY_URL&redirect_uri=MY_URI
```

The problem is I don't know whether the post to facebook was successful or not. I also don't know whether someone backed out of sharing. I would like to get this information.

I am not using FB.ui and cannot because I am sharing within an app webview and so the short answer is using this method doesn't work for me. But I like to be able to get a response the same way I could with it below if that is possible.

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'share',
          href: url,
          caption: caption,
          display: 'iframe',
      }, function(response){
         alert(response);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: why exactly do you want to know if the user shared something? what is the use case for this?

Comment: I want to know if the user shared something. The use case for this is when the user returns back to the redirect uri page, that some alert comes up that says you successful shared to facebook. Otherwise you get back and you don't know what happened

Comment: If something went wrong, the dialog should tell the user about it on its own. There is not need for your app to interfere with how this process works.